# Viewchild is undefined inside then()

Tags: angular, undefined, viewchild

**EDIT**

The problem was the "async await".

I remove the async await and just return the Promise.

For some reason the then() inside of async await lose the data about objects of class.

Any explanation? Thank you all :)

---

**QUESTION**

I have a View child which is undefined when I try use it inside a then()

## Code

ViewChild

```
@ViewChild('listaLecturas') listaLecturas!: ITBlistaComponent
```

HTML

```
<div class="recepcion-lista-lecturas">
    <itb-lista #listaLecturas [entidadActiva]="false" [parametros]="parametrosProductos" [configuracionColumnas]="configuracionProductos" [activarFiltro]="false"></itb-lista>
</div>
```

Methods

```
private async cargarLecturas(): Promise<void> {
    delete this.parametrosProductos['accion']
    this.parametrosProductos['accion'] = 'LEER_RECEPCION_PROMOCION'
    console.log(this.listaLecturas) // HERE IS DEFINED

    await this.datos.mantenimiento('LEER_RECEPCION_PROMOCION', this.parametrosProductos)
      .then( (registros) => this.montarLecturas(registros) )
      .catch( (error) => console.log(error))
  }

  private montarLecturas( registros: any ): void {
    this.listaLecturas.montarRegistros(registros) // HERE IS UNDEFINED
  }
```

The weird thing is that is defined before the then()

## Debugger

Defined
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4yea.png)

Undefined
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1f8o8.png)

I tried pass the component as argument in the method:

```
private async cargarLecturas(): Promise<void> {
    delete this.parametrosProductos['accion']
    this.parametrosProductos['accion'] = 'LEER_RECEPCION_PROMOCION'
    console.log(this.listaLecturas)

    await this.datos.mantenimiento('LEER_RECEPCION_PROMOCION', this.parametrosProductos)
      .then( (registros) => this.montarLecturas(registros, this.listaLecturas) )
      .catch( (error) => console.log(error))
  }

  private montarLecturas( registros: any, lista: ITBlistaComponent): void {
    lista.montarRegistros(registros)
  }
```

But still undefined.

Comment: is `cargarLecturas` called after ngAfterViewInit?

Comment: @enno.void Yes, this method is called when user make a change in one input.

Comment: I feel that with `{` `}` works: `.then( (registros) => {this.montarLecturas(registros) })` but I'm not pretty sure :(

Answer (score 0):

Is your `#listaLecturas` inside an *ngIf? It could be the reason why it can't be found in the template.

Comment: No, is not inside *ngIf. Anyway this have no sense, because before the then() is already defined. You can see this in the captures of the debugger.